# How to change bar position without affecting the results?

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, bar-chart

I'm new to R and im trying to change the position of a bar on a bar chart but my results have changed too. Here is the chart : [Chart of age](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvI73.png)

[image]

when I use the code :

```
positions <- c("Moins de 18 ans","18 a 22 ans", "23 a 27 ans", "33 a 37 ans","38 ans et plus")
p + theme_classic() + scale_x_discrete(limits = positions)
```

This is the results I have:
[Chart of age 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9ayH.png)

[image]

and the message :

```
    Warning messages:
1: Removed 86 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count). 
2: Removed 86 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count).
```

I don't know what to do with this. Someone help me please!

Comment: Could we see some data and the code you use to create the chart?  Also, I see 6 categories in the first chart and only 5 in your positions object.

Comment: I see now where the problem was. My  object "positions" had only 5 categories. That's why my results were affected. Thanks @RyanMorton!

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided the data, I can show how to rearrange bars using dummy data. To sort bar graph, essentially you need to sort data on variables you are using as x-axis in plot.

```
vec = c(rep("a", 30), rep("b", 20), rep("c", 10))
df = as.data.frame(table(vec)) # Create dummy data frame
```

Dataframe `df` looks like this -

```
  vec Freq
1   a   30
2   b   20
3   c   10
```

The plot will be -

```
df %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = vec, y = Freq)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") # default plot
```

[image]

Now, I want bars in order b,a,c. All I need to do is sort my dataframe in the same order -

```
df$vec = factor(df$vec, levels = c("b", "a", "c")) # assign levels in order you want to see the bar-plot
df = df[order(df$vec),] # sort dataframe on your x-variable

df %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = vec, y = Freq)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") # barplot will be sorted on levels of factor now
```

The output of above code is -

[image]

I haven't done rest of the formatting, but from your graphs, you are good with that. By following these steps, your data shouldn't change when reordering the bars. If you can share your data, I can better understand if it solves your problem.